# Node express database connection failing on local developing

Tags: java, node.js, postgresql, express, ubuntu

So long story short I'm trying to connect to my database using node and since its an assignment, most of the connections routes are already set and functional since its what I was told, however there should be a problem with how the connections are set because supposedly its a non-production project so it shouldn't require me for any credentials while trying to connect to the database. Anyway here's my error:

```
Started on http://localhost:3001
internal/crypto/keys.js:322
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string 
or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null 
    at prepareSecretKey (internal/crypto/keys.js:322:11)
    at new Hmac (internal/crypto/hash.js:113:9)
    at Object.createHmac (crypto.js:147:10)
    at createHMAC (/home/sam/express-jobly/node_modules/pg/lib/sasl.js:133:17)
    at Hi (/home/sam/express-jobly/node_modules/pg/lib/sasl.js:137:13)
    at Object.continueSession (/home/sam/express-jobly/node_modules/pg/lib/sasl.js:32:24)
    at Client._handleAuthSASLContinue (/home/sam/express-jobly/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:248:10)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /home/sam/express-jobly/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12
    at Parser.parse (/home/sam/express-jobly/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

Below is my config.js script.

```
"use strict";

/** Shared config for application; can be required many places. */

require("dotenv").config();
require("colors");

const SECRET_KEY = process.env.SECRET_KEY || "secret-dev";

const PORT = +process.env.PORT || 3001;

// Use dev database, testing database, or via env var, production database
function getDatabaseUri() {
  return (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test")
      ? "jobly_test"
      : process.env.DATABASE_URL || "jobly";
}

// Speed up bcrypt during tests, since the algorithm safety isn't being tested
//
// WJB: Evaluate in 2021 if this should be increased to 13 for non-test use
const BCRYPT_WORK_FACTOR = process.env.NODE_ENV === "test" ? 1 : 12;

console.log("Jobly Config:".green);
console.log("SECRET_KEY:".yellow, SECRET_KEY);
console.log("PORT:".yellow, PORT.toString());
console.log("BCRYPT_WORK_FACTOR".yellow, BCRYPT_WORK_FACTOR);
console.log("Database:".yellow, getDatabaseUri());
console.log("---");

module.exports = {
  SECRET_KEY,
  PORT,
  BCRYPT_WORK_FACTOR,
  getDatabaseUri,
};
```

I tried updating the dependencies, tried resetting the venv, At this point I'm not sure where to look at. My hard guess would be to see if my current PostgreSQL(yes I need to use this one) is using any credentials (it shouldn't), but any advice? I appreciate any help :)

Comment: share the piece of code where you are making the connection

Comment: "use strict";
const { Client } = require("pg");
const { getDatabaseUri } = require("./config");

let db;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  db = new Client({
    connectionString: getDatabaseUri(),
    ssl: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
  });
} else {
  db = new Client({
    connectionString: getDatabaseUri()
  });
}

db.connect();

module.exports = db;                                                                                                                 @Kamran

Comment: you can update in Question itself

Comment: Connection String should be something like this: postgres://user:password@host:5432/database , are you sure this is correct?

Comment: It should be correct, since fixing it is not part of my assignment but I guess I have no choice, project doesn't even have a .env file... anyways imma try that way and let you know!